# Listen to a Vue event from Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events

I have a Vue component which emits the `change` event.

```js
  methods: {
    onSelect(value) {
      this.open = false
      if (value === this.value) return
      this.$emit('change', value)
    },
  }
```

I am importing this component into an .astro component. (basically Vanilla JS/HTML)

```
  <VisSelect client:load brand={brand} name={selectId} placeholder={placeholder} label={label} required={required} options={options} />
```

I am adding an event listener to my document (tried different selectors, including the selector under which the component is mounted) listening to `change` but it's not fired.

```js
document.addEventListener('change', (e) => console.log(e))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like with the web-components, create ref to the top div (for example `selected`) and dispatch [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent):

```
onSelect(value) {
  this.open = false
  if (value === this.value) return
  this.$refs.selected.dispatchEvent(
    new CustomEvent('change', {
      detail: { value },
      bubbles: true,
      composed: true,
    })
  );
}
```

and then get the datail You provided in the event:

```
document.addEventListener('change', (e) => console.log(e.detail))
```

Comment: I ideally wouldnt like to change the actual vue component as its not in my direct control and other vue applications are using it.

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos seems to me like you want something that should not be done. If you have one part of the code talking to another, usually it is called API, you need to build some kind of contract between them.

In this answer API is established. And it keeps your components loosely coupled.

If you are asking for some "magic" way of listening for vue js actions, even if it exist it is most likely not what you want to do.